# Metal Gear Solid 4 game time while paused

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

Does the time while in the pause menu counts as played time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pause and cutscenes count as gametime.  I believe only OS interruption (Playstation button) will stop game time.

Comment: Does the time under that select button pause counts too?